# Honeypot used as as a proxy?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, honeypot

I'm running Kali Linux on my system at home to practice pentesting. If I implement a honeypot on my system could it be possible to use that as some sort of proxy server? I was thinking it wouldn't be ideal since it is running on my own network still. Even so, say I was to find a honeypot on someone else's server could I use that as some sort of proxy to bounce connections or somewhat?

What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to try and mask my IP through a honeypot and I know this probably wouldn't be possible locally. Is it possible if I was to connect to someone else's honeypot and mask my IP through that since they are assigned their own IPs?

Comment: If I understand you right you don't intend to use the honeypot to attract and study attackers but to hide your own IP? That is not really what a honeypot is for.

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm asking I'm just asking if it's possible. I know that's not what a honeypot is for but I'm curious within reason about this.

Comment: Then it simply depends on the honeypot. There are special case honeypots which cannot do it but you could also setup your own honeypot with your own ideas and also add a proxy there. A honeypot is just a computer with some software. But don't expect to have a proxy included in some honeypot software, because it makes no sense for a honeypot, at least not a harmless proxy like you want to use.

Comment: Okay thank you. Could you place an abbreviated answer on some suggestions on what software I could play with and give me ideas on some proxies to use with the honeypot?

Comment: Just because you want to use the proxy at some general purpose computer which is also used as honeypot does not make it a topic for security.se. Setting up a proxy for your own purpose is more a topic for superuser.com.

Comment: Okay, fair enough,

Comment: Since honeypots are designed to detect intruders, you would most definitely be noticed doing something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honeypots are designed to not be used as a launchpad for further attacks within a network. They are closed systems to trap an attacker.

At least, that's the intent. It is possible that you could find a vulnerability in the honeypot software that would allow you to pivot into the network. At that point, your requirements are to find and exploit that vulnerability and then install or configure a proxy for your purposes.

As there is not a "standard" way to do this and it is up to the individual honeypots, systems, and administrators in each case, there isn't much more to say as an answer.